# How do you determine the namespace of a function?

Tags: r, namespaces

Given a function, how do you determine which namespace it has come from?

For example, if I type `mean.default` at the command prompt, the output includes the fact that it is in the base package.  I want to be able to do something like `getNamespace(mean.default)` and have it return "base" (or the actual base environment).

There is a `getNamespace` function but seems to only accept package names rather than function names.

`print.function` uses internal code to retrieve the namespace.  I got as far as browsing `do_printfunction` in `src/main/print.c` but then gave up.

Comment: Three excellent answers; thanks all.  Tough to choose between them since they all work, so I'm going with the popular vote.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I very recently learned about `find()` which seems to do just this.

```
R> find("ls")
[1] "package:base"
R> find("na.locf")
[1] "package:zoo"
```

Comment: Does the order tell us anything? `find("select")` returns `[1] "package:MASS"  "package:dplyr"` will this mean `MASS::select()` will get called when `select()`? or does the order not mean anything?

Comment: Yes, and it reflects the order in which you loaded them into your session. So `library(MASS); library(dplyr)` leads to different outcomes from `library(dplyr); library(MASS)`.  Needless to say, such shadowing is bad practice.

Answer (score 19):

You want `getNamespaceName` + `environment`:

```
getNamespaceName(environment(mean.default))
# [1] "base"
```

Comment: With character input: `getNamespaceName(environment(get("mean.default")))`.

Answer (score 17):

`findFunction` is another option and `?findFunction` says you should use it instead of `find` with `mode="function"`.  The result of `findFunction` is a list of the environment(s) where the visible versions of the function are located.

Answer (score 2):

This function searches functions in the loaded namespaces and global environment:

```
getEnvName <- function(f) {
    attached <- c(environmentName(.GlobalEnv), loadedNamespaces())
    envs <- c(.GlobalEnv, lapply(attached[-1], .getNamespace))
    attached[vapply(envs, function(env) exists(f, env, inherits = FALSE), logical(1))]
}
median <- function() {}
getEnvName("median")
#> [1] "R_GlobalEnv" "stats"
getEnvName(".try_quietly")
#> [1] "tools"
getEnvName("getEnvName")
#> [1] "R_GlobalEnv"
```

Answer (score 0):

`getNamespaceName()` as proposed in [@hadley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433626/7196903) doesn't work when the function isn't in the current namespace.

The following does:

```
environmentName(findFunction(f = "str_detect",
                             where = getNamespace("stringr"))[[1]])
```

Set the `where` argument according to your needs. Its [documentation](https://rdrr.io/r/methods/GenericFunctions.html):

> The environment, namespace, or search-list position from which to search for objects. By default, start at the top-level environment of the calling function, typically the global environment (i.e., use the search list), or the namespace of a package from which the call came. It is important to supply this argument when calling any of these functions indirectly. With package namespaces, the default is likely to be wrong in such calls.