# Name of a package for a given function in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you you determine the namespace of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429180/how-do-you-you-determine-the-namespace-of-a-function)

I don't know how to do this... How do you know the package name for a certain function in R? I would like to have a function that given the name of a function, returns the name of the package that owns it. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Andrie Well spotted. Given that all packages now have a namespace, the Answer by hadley in the Q&A you link to strikes me as being the best solution.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: Why is it better than `findFunction`? (I'm just trying to imagine explaining to a student why they should use `getNamespaceName(environment(foo))` rather than `findFunction(foo)` -- the former seems a little magical, and if it doesn't have significant advantages ...)

Comment: @BenBolker `find()` & `findFunction()` don;t return *just* the namespace (hence package) name. Their results need further processing. Hadley's returns just the package name as a character. I might prefer that for writing a function or programming, but for user code the others are fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be better solutions, but `find("functionname")` seems to work reasonably well?  However, it only works for loaded packages.

```
> find("strwidth")
[1] "package:graphics"
> find("qplot")
character(0)
> library(ggplot2)
> find("qplot")
[1] "package:ggplot2"
>
```

(If you need the raw name of the package you can use `gsub("^package:","",results)`)

(The answers to the previous question linked by Andrie include this answer; they don't give the bit about `gsub`, and they all seem to share the issue of not finding non-loaded packages.)

Here's a quick hack to find functions even in non-loaded packages:

```
findAllFun <- function(f) {
    h <- help.search(paste0("^",f,"$"),agrep=FALSE)
    h$matches[,"Package"]
}

findAllFun("qplot")
## "ggplot2"
findAllFun("lambertW")
## "emdbook"    "VGAM" 
> findAllFun("xYplot")
## "Hmisc" "lattice"
```

If you need to find functions in non-*installed* packages (i.e. searching CRAN), then `findFn` from the `sos` package will be your friend.

Comment: and what about with the non-loaded packages?