# Is it possible to get the environment that a value originated from?

Tags: r

I know that, in a fresh R session, `lm` is `stats::lm`.

Is there a way to inspect the `lm` variable in order to figure out that it comes from the `stats` environment?

Comment: Yep; here is a clever way of doing that: https://sebastiansauer.github.io/finds_funs/

Comment: Do any of the answers here solve your problem? [Name of a package for a given function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553755/name-of-a-package-for-a-given-function-in-r)