# Determine the namespace of a function within an anonymous function

Tags: r

My question is very similar to this one: [How do you you determine the namespace of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429180/how-do-you-you-determine-the-namespace-of-a-function)

We can get the environment of a function with `environment`, and possibly combine it with `getNamespaceName`:

```
environment(mean)
#> <environment: namespace:base>
getNamespaceName(environment(mean))
#> [1] "base"
```

I would like to achieve something similar for an anonymous function:

```
anon_f <- function(x) mean(x)
```

The environment for this function is obviously the global environment, and there is no namespace:

```
environment(anon_f)
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Is it possible to somehow "step into" the anonymous function and get the environment/namespace of the function within the anonymous function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the pryr library, which is a collection of tools for computing on the language.

```
library(pryr)
f <- fget(fun_calls(anon_f))
getNamespaceName(environment(f))
# [1] "base"
```

For multiple calls in the function body, you would have to use a loop.  I don't use this library regularly, so there may be an even easier way.